# Yes it is, but it’s getting warmer. / Yes, but it’s getting warmer

Tags: pronouns

If we speak about the weather: "Is it cold outside?"

I suppose I can answer both versions, right?

> **Yes it is, but** it’s getting warmer.
>
> **Yes, but** it’s getting warmer.

If I understand it correctly, "it is" is not redundant but also not obligatory in the first sentence. It might be used for emphasis, right?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.  Heh heh.

Comment: The first is simply less terse than the second: not more emphatic. To be emphatic you'd need "it really is" or "it certainly is".

Comment: @Old Brixtonian, I guess if I say "Yes, it really is" then to say "but it’s getting warmer." isn't idiomatic. We need to choose between "really is" and "it’s getting warmer.". Right?

Comment: @Sergei: Well - it may have been **extremely** cold yesterday. So although it's cold outside today, it's not as cold as it was. Or perhaps you have heard, seen or read a weather forecast which told you today would be warmer than yesterday. If you believe the forecast you might say, "Yes it really/certainly is, but it's getting warmer." In the UK we don't trust weather forecasts, so we would probably say, "Yes it really/certainly is, but _they say_ it's getting warmer." Or add the word "apparently" at the end and stress it heavily: "...but it's getting warmer - **apparently**."

Comment: You could use "Yes it is" in an unemphatic way, if you let it tail out with the implication "it is for now", rather than saying it sharply and emphatically.